# How to remove duplicate cases in switch in java

Tags: java, duplicates, sonarqube

I have sonarQube running but it says that there are duplicates within these lines of code. How do resolve this in a switch statement? I am just learning how unit testing in java works so any help would be great!

```java
switch () {
    case "M":
        campusLogo = "/watermark_main.png";
        break;
    case "IN":
        campusLogo = "/Watermark_IN.png";
        break;
    case "WA":
        campusLogo = "/Watermark_WA.png";
        break;
    case "MO":
        campusLogo = "/Watermark_MO.png";
        break;
    case "NC":
        campusLogo = "/Watermark_NC.png";
        break;
    case "NV":
        campusLogo = "/Watermark_NV.png";
        break;
    case "OH":
        campusLogo = "/Watermark_OH.png";
        break;
    case "TN":
        campusLogo = "/Watermark_TN.png";
        break;
    case "TX":
        campusLogo = "/Watermark_TX.png";
        break;

    default:
        campusLogo = "/watermark_main.png";
}
```

Comment: Have an intentional **fall-through** (might want to comment it though) instead of `break`ing each case. That said, I do not see a duplication here (other than the fact that you are assigning strings to a variable). Could you post the full warning message please?

Comment: Switch-expressions would be useful here. `campusLogo = switch (...) { ... };`

Comment: You could omit `case "M"` and let it fall to the default.

Comment: Why not just use a map? Or just string concatenation with some minor tweaks?

Comment: Also, all you do is appending the case code to the string. Might as well not have any switch/map and just do `campusLogo = "/Watermark_" + code + ".png"` (+ some minimal `if` check, maybe with a `Set<String> supportedCodes`, beforehand for `default`).

Comment: `case "M":
default:
        campusLogo = "/watermark_main.png";`

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe that all of these comments, along with the current one answer, are going in the wrong direction.  He's talking about SonarQube detecting a duplicate block.  That means his issue is that this entire switch statement is duplicated somewhere else in his repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think below solution should work for you:

```java
switch (choice) {
    case "IN":
    case "WA":
    case "MO":
    case "NC":
    case "NV":
    case "OH":
    case "TN":
    case "TX":
        campusLogo = "/Watermark_" + choice + ".png";
        break;

    default:
        campusLogo = "/watermark_main.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If SonarQube is saying you have duplicate blocks, that has little to do with the business logic you're showing here.  What SonarQube is telling you is that you have this exact same business logic duplicated in another class or method.  You should examine refactoring your project so that this switch statement only appears in one place.